# Fast for SharePoint - Crawl or Query Master Detail Data

Tags: 2010, fast-for-sharepoint, sharepoint-search

We have pictures stored in a document library where we keep their metadata like sand, people, smiling. (Picture Lib contains about 30 metadata fields) In another list, we store publishing history of pictures like it is published in Newspaper A on Page 13 on Date X, also published in Newspaper B on Page 2 on Date Y etc.. (Publish History List contains 8 fields)

When we search for a keyword and select a date interval, we want to get pictures labeled with the keyword that are published between selected date interval.

We have to crawl huge data. Custom pipeline stage is not an option in our case since it multiplies crawl duration.

Lookup column and projected columns may help, but on one hand picture library has too many fields and on the other publish history has multiple data on multiple columns.

Can anybody please give brief information about crawling and querying master/detail data in SharePoint Search and how can design the data/search architecture?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to create a BCS connector back to your lists. Create the relationship in your external content type. There are attributes on the Association that control what results are returned when a child item is crawled and returned in search. I have used this approach to search child items and return the parent record.

As Max indicates you can also "flatten" your data through BCS.

The real challenge once the Crawl and Query is working is returning a search result that makes sense. BCS Profile page can help you here too.

I hope that's not too vague.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SP.SE!

Query Master/Detail Data in search is always challenging - easiest would be to aggregate all data in one row, e.g with a timer job and then crawl this special list.

Alternatively you could create a custom protocol handler and index with it. This handler is a dll with your logic and aggregates the data - much faster then the custom pipeline stage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556429(v=office.14).aspx